# Trouble with ActionResult in unit test can't Assert.Equal on POST return value (asp.net core mvc web api)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, xunit

I'm new to testing .net core web APIs and am struggling to test the POST method on my API. I can assert the type of the ActionResult that is returned, but I can't seem to figure out how to compare the result to the fixture that I'm creating.

I've debugged the unit test and seen that the CreatedAtAction call is returning an ActionResult. The top-level Value is null. However, the Value for the Result has the item.

I feel like I'm missing a cast or something and my code should be expecting a CreatedAtActionResult or something, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work.

Here is the (POST) method from my controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> AddTodoItem(TodoItem item)
        {
            _context.TodoItems.Add(item);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = item.Id }, item);
        }
```

Here is my unit test:

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task PostTodoItem_ShouldPass()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();
            var item = fixture.Create<TodoItem>();
            var result = await _controller.AddTodoItem(item);
            Assert.IsType<ActionResult<TodoItem>>(result); // WORKS
            Assert.Equal(item, result.Value); // DOESN'T WORK!!
        }
```

I'm using Autofixture and the EF in-memory database for testing. All of this is getting set up in a shared database fixture class which runs before the unit test.

Here is my debugger output.

[image: debugger output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be an oddity in the object model here. I dont know the reason though.
You call *CreatedAtAction* which returns a *CreatedAtActionResult*. That has a Value property which is an object. This is what you're passing the *TodoItem* into and you can see it in your debugger output.

This class does NOT inherit from *ActionResult< T>*, but thats what your function returns. 
*ActionResult< T>* DOES have an implicit operator that allows it any type to be cast to it and one that is for *ActionResult* objects (not generic).

So when the compiler sees you returning a *CreatedAtActionResult*, it needs to turn that into the *ActionResult< T>* so it calls the implicit cast from *ActionResult* (as CreatedAtActionResult : ObjectResult : ActionResult).

Therefore to get the Todo for the comparison you want you need to:

```
 Assert.Equal(item, (result.Result as CreatedAtActionResult).Value); // SHOULD WORK!!
```

Comment: I used the .NET source to look this up btw. The [ActionResultOfT.cs is here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs)

The rest of the files/classes you use are in the same folder

Comment: Thx for the reply. Should have mentioned that I did try this but then it won't compile: "'ActionResult' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no accessible extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'ActionResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061) [Tests]".

Comment: I tried a couple of variations on casts too, but haven't been able to figure it out. Will try looking at the source. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the correct cast. I copied the wrong line from my VS instance.

Comment: This is perfect! Worked for me. Not sure why MS designed it this way but will dig into it a bit more. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Assert.Equal(item, result.Value); // DOESN'T WORK!!

Assert.Equal(item, ***((ObjectResult)actual.Result).Value***);  // Try this it should work